# Ideas for a interface layout

Tags: layout

Hope you get the idea of what I'm trying to layout.

I have an interface where I display all the information of a user (name, age, height,etc etc) and I also want to display the last weight of this user. Something like this:

Weight: 45KG | new Weight | show record

Where new weight override the last weight and show record (show as a popup all of the records that the user have in a graphic).

What I'm not sure how to do exactly is how to display the information below this graphic or elsewhere so I can give the user option to edit or even delete one of the past record.

So any idea that can help me?

Comment: Please upload an image of the basic idea, it's much easier to help you then. Since your reputation is too low to upload an image, use any free web page that does this - ImageShack® or similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use grid to display all weight changes or allow to select point on graph and use popup to delete or some shortcut to delete selected point (use legend).